# inserting dynamic text into shape vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert dynamic text into a shape which is also a macro button. Every time I click it, it should give me today's date. I have looked at different queries, but I am still lost on this. It returns me error 438.

```
Sub shapetextdynamic()

With ActiveSheet
.Shapes("Rectangle16").Select
.Selection.Characters.Text = Now()

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I still get an error of 438

Comment: `.Shapes("Rectangle16").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Date`

Comment: FYI when you call a sub from a click on a shape then `Application.Caller` has the name of the clicked-on shape.  So you can use `.Shapes(Application.Caller)` instead of `.Shapes("Rectangle16")`

Comment: Yes BigBen, thank you so much. That seems to work.